# Internet Explorer 10 - CSS3 transition not working

Tags: css, colors, transition

That transition thing works in Chrome but does not work IE 10. Though it supports CSS3, why doesn't it work?

```
.box {

    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.2s linear;
    background-color:#EBEBEB;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color:#7bae31;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE10 should support CSS3 transitions without the need for a vendor prefix. Drop the -webkit- part of your css,  so that it just reads:

```
transition:background-color 0.2s linear;
```

You can see it working at:

http://jsfiddle.net/CnYtu/2/

For future reference, you can check IE CSS3 compatibility at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx